# How to run my application module from command line?

Tags: android, gradle

I have two applications modules in my project:

- app1
- app2

How do I run app2 from the command line?

```
./gradlew assembleDebug app2
```

Tested this and it doesn't work, getting the next message:

> Task 'app2' not found in root project

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would use:

```
cd app2; ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

(assuming that I used the Gradle wrapper command-line script, which I wouldn't)

However, this should also work:

```
./gradlew app2:assembleDebug
```

if your `settings.gradle` file is set up to reference these app modules.

See "57.4 Running tasks by their absolute path" in [the Multi-Project Builds page in the Gradle docs](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html).